# Rails won't read environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ubuntu

Ruby 1.9.3p327, Rails 3.2.9, omniauth 1.1.1, omniauth-google-oauth2, Ubuntu 12.10.

omniauth.rb intializer says:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_KEY'], ENV['OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_SECRET'], {access_type: 'online', approval_prompt: ''}
end
```

~/.bashrc says:

```
### Added for omniauth
export ENV['OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_KEY']="693094632646.apps.googleusercontent.com"
export ENV['OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_SECRET']="693126830846.apps.googleusercontent.com"
```

(I changed the numbers but I'm keeping the strings so you see what I mean.)

I restarted my Rails server, and still when I try to authenticate with Google, I get `Missing required parameter: client_id`. So, for some reason, Ruby isn't reading this environment var, and I'm completely lost.

Any ideas why? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Full .bashrc follows:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi


### Added for omniauth
export OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_KEY="5323094630846.apps.googleusercontent.com"
export OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_SECRET="693044132846.apps.googleusercontent.com"

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to add `ENV` when exporting, here's `~/.bashrc`:

```
export OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_KEY=693094632646.apps.googleusercontent.com
export OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_SECRET=693126830846.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

I think that will works :)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, but it still doesn't work. Upon further investigation, I found out that the .bashrc file just doesn't set these variables for some reason -- when I try to echo them from another shell script, I get nothing! Any idea why that can happen?

Comment: (Maybe the reason I can't echo is because I'm trying to do it from an interactive session... which .bashrc doesn't impact. In this case, I'm lost as to why it still doesn't work. Total noob here...)

Comment: make sure you put `export` line above `return` statement, sometime `.bashrc` contain line like `[[ $- != *i* ]] && return`, putting `export` above these line will works.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the case... Added my complete `.bashrc` above.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
export ENV['OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_KEY']="693094632646.apps.googleusercontent.com"
```

to

```
export OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_KEY="693094632646.apps.googleusercontent.com"
```

`ENV` is the array Rails creates when it reads the environment.